# OrientDB: How to remove specific lightweight edge?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, orientdb

I am using ruby on rails' gem [oriented](https://github.com/ruprict/oriented), which allows you to use the Java API to interface with Orient's database.

Say I have three vertices `v0 (rid #10:0)`, `v1 (rid #10:1)` and `v2 (rid #10:2)`, and then I add edges connecting them like so:

```
connection = Oriented.connection
graph = connection.graph

v0 = graph.getVertex("#10:0")
v1 = graph.getVertex("#10:1")
v2 = graph.getVertex("#10:2")

graph.addEdge(nil, v0, v1, 'owns')
graph.addEdge(nil, v0, v2, 'owns')
```

So now my database looks like this:

```
rid   | in_owns | out_owns
------|---------|-------------
#10:0 |         | #10:1, #10:2
#10:1 | #10:0   |
#10:2 | #10:0   |
```

And now I would like to remove the edge between #10:0 and #10:1, preferably using Java's API to do it, which oriented seems to support (couldn't find a way to run SQL queries inside a transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lightweight edges are like regular edges from TInkerPop Java API, so when you browse them and you want to delete one of it, use the TinkerPop API:

```
OrientEdge.remove();
```

Comment: But how do I get that edge? Since it's lightweight that means there is no document and the edge has no rid. From my understanding what I would need to do is access v0's `out_owns` property and remove the reference to v1 there, and then do the same to v1's `in_owns` property, but I could not achieve this

Comment: `Iterable<Edge> edges = v.getEdges(Direction.OUT, "friend");
for (Edge e : edges){
  if( (Integer) e.getProperty("age") > 10 )
    e.remove();
}`